# How to pause a CSS animation (marquee) on hover at predefined point?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Currently** at http://www.futurebreeze.com there's a marquee that has different texts scroll in from right that temporarily rest at the far left of the screen before they scroll out of sight further to the left.

Apart from the rest at the left, each scrolling text can be paused manually on mouse hover. However, this pause happens suddenly and also pauses when a text hasn't fully appeared or disappeared yet.

**The desired behaviour** is that, on mouse hover, a text first reaches its resting point at the left of the screen, then pauses until the mouse moves away again, after which the text scrolls out of sight at the left and the next text scrolls in from the right while adhering to the same desired pausing behavior.

**Question:** Is the desired behavior at all possible with `CSS` functionality and if so how? Or is there an alternative solution known that makes this possible, perhaps using an entirely different approach?

Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example: https://jsfiddle.net/appxe0g8/2/

Comment: Could you generate a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example we can help you with? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Done, I've added a JSFiddle URL!